# How to share only an image via Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

Using Linkedin via Buffer, I can share content with only an attached image.  ie no accompanying comment, url, or any text.  It is also possible via the web interface.

However, when using their share API, you are forced to include a URL and it displays with the content.   Buffer must be using the API in some way, so how do you get around this?

Comment: any update for this issue?

Comment: I believe LinkedIn has additional API endpoints available to certain customers ie Buffer.  I contacted them for additional access and was denied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking for the same solution.

[How to get large LinkedIn Image Share Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41846273/how-to-get-large-linkedin-image-share-format/42130674#42130674)

basically you just pass the image url  in *submitted-url* field and don't pass *submitted-image-url* paramter in the json.

I was unable to find a this solution in google and in stackoverflow. I hope this help someone in the future.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact JSON that you're using to achieve this result? I tried omitting the `submitted-image-url` parameter, but I'm still getting a post that looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/dhfeS

Comment: you can check out the link I have mention in my answer for more details.

the json should be like this:

`{   
    "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
    "content": {
        "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
        "submitted-url": "https://www.example.com/someimage.jpg"
    },
    "visibility": {
        "code": "anyone"
    }
}`

Comment: `{ "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!", "content": { "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources", "submitted-url": "http://www.mulierchile.com/happy-picture/happy-picture-002.jpg" }, "visibility": { "code": "anyone" } }` produces https://imgur.com/a/jztdZ

Comment: This question is about creating a share that doesn't include any "accompanying comment, url, or [text]". So, removing the fields that we don't want, we are left with `{ "content": { "submitted-url": "http://www.mulierchile.com/happy-picture/happy-picture-002.jpg" }, "visibility": { "code": "anyone" } } `. This produces https://imgur.com/a/JYL8Y. The text at the bottom is undesirable. Are you seeing something different?