# How to get large LinkedIn Image Share Format

Tags: asp.net, linkedin-api

I am using linkedin api to share post on linkedin which look like this:

[image]

How to get make post like this through api:
[image]

I am trying all combination of post body but am not able to post content like above.

```
{   
    "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
    "content": {
        "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
        "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
        "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
        "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
        },
        "visibility": {
            "code": "anyone"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If someone looking for a solution for this, The trick that I have found it.

so basically the solution is to pass the image url in the *submitted-url* field and don't pass the *submitted-image-url* parameter.

so instead of passing this:

```
{   
    "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
    "content": {
        "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
        "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
        "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
        "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
    },
    "visibility": {
        "code": "anyone"
    }
}
```

which will give:[image]

you pass the following:

```
{   
    "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
    "content": {
        "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
        "submitted-url": "https://www.example.com/someimage.jpg"
    },
    "visibility": {
        "code": "anyone"
    }
}
```

which will give this:

[image]

Note that I don't pass *submitted-image-url* and *description* in the json. Description does not show on the post, so there's no point of passing anything in that field.

Comment: Can you please post the *exact* JSON that you provide to accomplish this? I used the code in the second snippet in your answer, (changing only the `submitted-url` field to be a valid image) and I'm still getting a post that looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/dhfeS

Comment: Also, can you please clarify which version of the API you're using? We're on v1; if you're on v2, that might explain why it's working differently for us. Thanks! :)

Comment: i am using v1 too.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass " " as the title and you will get a card that seems to be an picture.